# GNU make cheat-sheet

Tags: gnu-make

I'm learning to work with GNU make and I'm reading the manual (which is very good) but I'm missing a cheat-sheet for quick reference. Is there any good?

Note: It's quite hard to find to google this.

Comment: I've been using make for years and I still need a cheatsheet

Comment: There’s also (including TeX source code) https://github.com/mxenoph/cheat_sheets. I have it hanging above my desk at work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have made my own. It is definitely not a perfect one but it served me well:

- http://martinvseticka.eu/temp/make/presentation.html
- http://martinvseticka.eu/temp/make/normal.html

Note: The source for the slides is [the official manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).

Answer (score 27):

Here is one by [Frank Schacherer](https://web.archive.org/web/20171218110823/http://www.schacherer.de/frank/technology/tools/make.html).

Comment: Link is dead :(

Comment: I just replaced by an archive.org link.

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful: https://users.cs.duke.edu/~ola/courses/programming/Makefiles/Makefiles.html

I use it occasionally for a quick reference.

Comment: Thanks! It's not exactly as nice as I would like but I'm thinking about making such an cheat-sheet myself (and incorporating useful info from the manual and this document). Thanks again!